# Is there a better way to parse a mongodb query in go?

Tags: go, mgo

Hi I got a sort of complex aggregate query that I must write with mgo, but I got really dazed when work it out half way :-(, Is there a better way to do that ?

Here is a console query aggregate command that I have tested and it works.

```
db.event.aggregate([{$match:{clktime:{$gt:1425289561}}},{$group:{"_id":{$subtract:["$clktime",{$mod:["$clktime", 60*5]}]}, count:{$sum:1}}}])
```

And here is what I have got so far:

```
c.Pipe([]bson.M{bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"clktime": bson.M{"$gt": 1425289561}}}, bson.M{"$group": bson.M{"_id": bson.M{"$subtract": []bson.M{bson.M{"$clktime"}, bson.M{"$mod": []bson.M{bson.M{"$clktime"}, bson.M{60 * 5}}}}}}, "count": bson.M{"$sum": 1}}})
```

It says that **there is a missing key in map literal**, but I can't find where.

I thought human beings don't deserve that, I am so desperate T_T.

Is there a better or humanity way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a better way. Break your code into multiple lines and use comma after last element in map or array. Then the code will be formatted automatically and you will also get a readable error messages indicating line.

```
package main

type M map[string]M

var x = M{
    "a": M{
        "b": M{},
        "c": M{},
    },
}
```

By the way. Look at this part `bson.M{"$clktime"}, bson.M{60 * 5}}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    x := []bson.M{{"$match": bson.M{"clktime": bson.M{"gt": 1425289561}}},{"$group": bson.M{"_id": bson.M{"$subtract": []interface{}{"$clktime", bson.M{"$mod": []interface{}{"$clktime", 60 * 5}}}}, "count": bson.M{"$sum": 1}}}}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what this is doing?

Comment: I find it's illuminating to using `[]interface{}` when come to arrays `["$clktime", 60*5]` in the query command, although the sentence you write may not be correct in this situation, inspired me, through, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have write this out, but the suggestions @Grzegorz give(which to split the building or query to multi lines for convenience) and also considered @Morty's opinion(which using `[]interface{}` when come to arrays in query command). And here is what I got which works:

```
q := []bson.M{
    bson.M{
        "$match": bson.M{
            "clktime": bson.M{
                "$gt": 1425289561,
            },
        },
    },
    bson.M{
        "$group": bson.M{
            "_id": bson.M{
                "$subtract": []interface{}{
                    "$clktime",
                    bson.M{
                        "$mod": []interface{}{
                            "$clktime",
                            60 * 5,
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
            "count": bson.M{"$sum": 1},
        },
    },
}
```

Hope it will be helpful for other people come to similar issue.